# Was Bhairavi yogeswari, the Tantra-Guru of Sri Ramakrishna, a disciple of Sri Trailanga Swami?

Tags: guru, ramakrishna, trailanga-swami

According to a biography of Sri Trailanga Swami, Bhairavi Yogeswari, the Tantra-Guru of Sri Ramakrishna was a disciple of Sri Trailanga Swami and it was Sri Trailanga Swami Who ordered Him to go to Dakshineswar to teach Sri Ramakrishna.

Are these informations supported by evidences available in the Ramakrishna Literature?